# Does the recent picture of the black hole have a native resolution?

Tags: black-holes, image-processing

Can the resolution be measured in pixels? If so, what is the pixel resolution?

Comment: Unclear what you mean. The released images have many pixels per resolution element. They are not pixels in a camera.

Comment: Hi Rob. Can the recent picture of the black hole have something that is the equivalent or something comparable to a native resolution  or total pixel resolution?